# Using SQL server temporal tables in power bi for monthly data

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017, powerbi-desktop

The goal is to prepare a power BI report that provides historical data based on month-year selected by the user.

To get data for all available months, I am trying to do something like below

```
SELECT * FROM Employee   
    FOR SYSTEM_TIME    
        AS OF <<End of month>>
```

I want to run this query for every month available in the history table then union them all in a single table.

This way, I will be able to let the user select any month-year in power bi and filter this union table based on the selection.

The only question is that, **how do I retrieve all available months from history table of a temporal table**, so that I can iterate over them and run the above query for each?

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same query.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to create a view (or even run a select statement) that hard codes all the dates and unions them up.

```
SELECT * FROM Employee 
FOR SYSTEM_TIME 
AS OF '2010-01-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Employee 
FOR SYSTEM_TIME 
AS OF '2010-02-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Employee 
FOR SYSTEM_TIME 
AS OF '2010-03-01'
```

This is the 'brute force' method.

It's probably possible to do something much smarter in M (the import language in Power BI) but I'm unable to find a good example

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I figured something out. I will write a procedure, that gets distinct month years from the temporal table and then iterate over them in while loop (or something similar) and get everything under a single table. I will post if it works once I try it out.